# Calender issue with time zone

Tags: java, calendar, dozer

I'm having a weird situation with Java Calendar. I'm using dozer mapper to map the objects.

I want to write a method that will convert this object to the following format. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

say element 2010-11-11T09:30:47.000Z

```
public Calender getValue(Date source,Calender c) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calendar.setTime(source);
return calendar;
}
```

When I run the program, it is printing
2010-11-11T04:00:47.000Z - Because we are setting the Timezone to be GMT, (9.30 - 5.30 = 4.00)

I want my object to have same format and value.if I don't set TimeZone to GMT, it will show as 2008-11-21T09:30:47.000+05:30.

I want it as 2010-11-11T09:30:47.000Z.

I tried added 5.30 to calender.

```
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
```

then it works.But if this is ran from any other place, difference won't be 5.30.So I cannot add 5.30 to calenderget

Is there any way to get rid of this problem? **I want to return Calender object.**

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use a pattern. F.E:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
```

Also,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformatyyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String date_to_string = dateformatyyyyMMdd.format(dateNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SimpleDateFormat like this.

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter, FORMATTER;
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
   String oldDate = "2011-03-10T11:54:30.207Z";
   Date date = formatter.parse(oldDate.substring(0, 24));
   FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   System.out.println("OldDate-->"+oldDate);
   System.out.println("NewDate-->"+FORMATTER.format(date));
```

Output OldDate-->2011-03-10T11:54:30.207Z NewDate-->10-Mar-2011 11:54:30.207